# Configuring Spring and JBoss

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss

We are building a series of new Spring applications that have common supporting JAR files. Within the applications deployed in a Tomcat environment the world is good. These same JARs need to be accessed by legacy applications that are running under JBoss in a non-Spring environment. Can someone point me to a location or explain here how to either configure Spring and JBoss so the JARs function properly or how to package them so that the Spring dependencies are part of the JAR. Maven is in the mix as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define Spring as a module

The following are steps to create a Spring module:

1.Download the desired version of Spring. For this example we are using Spring 3.1.1.

2.Create the directory:
$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/springframework/spring/main.

3.Copy the Spring libraries you downloaded to that directory.

4.Create module.xml with the following contents under that directory. Make sure these  correspond to the libraries' names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.springframework.spring">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
    <module name="javax.api" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/> 
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Here is an absolute minimal module.xml (the different Spring version is irrelevant):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.springframework.spring">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-expression-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

5.Put the following jboss-deployment-structure.xml in your application archive (WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml for WAR or META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml for EAR or EJB-jar) to use the above module:

If you're using JBoss EAP 6.1.x and greater, then use below:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.springframework.spring" export="true" meta-inf="export"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

If JBoss EAP 6.0.x, then use below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>   
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.springframework.spring" export="true">
        <imports>
          <include path="META-INF**"/>
          <include path="org**"/>
        </imports>
        <exports>
          <include path="META-INF**"/>
          <include path="org**"/>
        </exports>
      </module>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Note: The meta-inf on the module in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml was added in JBoss EAP 6.1.0, which allows the files in the META-INF of a resource to be visible. Since this was not available in JBoss EAP 6.0.x, the  section allows you to get access to the META-INF directory which is not visible by default.

Note: The Spring Framework module should not include resources such as servlet-api.jar, xml-apis.jar, jta-api.jar, and other APIs. These APIs are implemented by either the JDK or JBoss and trying to use a different version of the API will lead to classloading issues and other problems.

Note: The Spring module should include all of its non Java / JavaEE dependencies. The Spring module can depend on javax.api / javaee.api provided by JBoss and any public JBoss module, but for other dependencies Spring has such as aopalliance, they would need to be included as resources in the module or in another custom module.

Comment: Followed these steps and now I'm getting a file not found error when it tries to load the first jar. The file name is spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar and I've tried both '<resource-root path="spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>' and '<resource-root path="org.springframework.spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>' any suggestions @anup-dey?

Comment: I figured out the problem for the file not found.